# Sending AT commands through gpio pins

Tags: gsm

I am working on Toradex VF-50 SoM using the evaluation board. I have a quectel M10 Modem. The modem is connected to the board using  gpio pins and not on the serial port. There are many solutions available for configuring the modem over the serial port. But i need to configure and use the modem over the gpio pins. I have connected the Rx(36),Tx(38),Gnd,Vcc and 5v with the gpio. Now i need a sample code on how to configure and send AT commands over this modem. The os in the SoM is WinCE6. I need to develop the code is Visual Studio 2008. please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend connecting a modem to GPIOs which do not have UART functionality! This makes your SW unnecessary complex and you load the CPU with work which could be done more efficient by the UART HW.
The Toradex Colibri VF50 has many pins with UART functionality, you can use the [Pinout designer](http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/pinout-designer) to find a good solution for you.

In case there are some good reasons you have to use other pins you can use the GPIOLibary for an easy way to program the GPIOs. It comes with code samples:
http://developer.toradex.com/software/windows-embedded-compact/toradex-ce-libraries-and-code-samples

I don't have a link but I guess there is sample code how to emulate/bit bang a serial port.